# How to access variables in Windows Workflow in VB expressions constructed at runtime

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

I hope I'm not being misguided in trying to do this, but I'd like to set the VB expression for an InArgument in Windows Workflow at runtime and have it access variables that are currently in scope.

In particular, I'd like to change the following bit of example code to say `new VisualBasicValue<string>("String.Format(\"Hello {0}\", FirstName)` - that is, I'd like to stop specifying the explicit string "World" and start passing in a name to the workflow from `Main`. I add a new InArgument called `FirstName` to the workflow itself, and then try and access it as above, but it doesn't work - I'm guessing because it doesn't know what `FirstName` is referring to at the point at which it compiles the expression. Please do you know of an alternative way to accomplish the same goal?

(The context for this problem is that I'm writing code to run different types of calculation. A calculation takes a string parameter that contains a VB expression that must be run to get some data from one of a variety of different locations. I want to specify the VB expression for each different calculation type in a .config file, then evaluate those expressions "on-the-fly" at runtime when it becomes necessary to run the various different calculations.)

```
using System.Activities;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities;

namespace SMG_RuntimeExpressionTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var wf = new Workflow();
            wf.Text = new VisualBasicValue<string>("String.Format(\"Hello {0}\", \"World\")");
            WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(wf);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you're misunderstanding/misusing the input arguments usage or maybe I don't understand exactly what you want. Anyway, why aren't you using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd986834.aspx) `Invoke` overload to pass arguments into to the workflow?

Comment: @Jota: There's a trade-off between type-safety and performance when choosing between different ways of doing `Invoke` - this way is more type-safe, the other way has better performance when you're going to be invoking the workflow multiple times with different arguments. Since I'm only invoking it once here, type-safety wins out.

Comment: @StuartGolodetz I got into this now, i have to follow your (a) path : parse the expressions and evaluate them at run time myself. Meanwhile, have you found a better solution?

Comment: @OlaruMircea: Afraid not, sorry - the point at which I asked the question (late 2011) was pretty much the only time I ever got into Windows Workflow and I haven't really used it since.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a couple of blog posts on arguments [WF4: Passing Arguments to Activities](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2009/09/14/wf4-passing-arguments-to-activities.aspx) and [Passing arguments to Workflow Activities (again)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/05/26/passing-arguments-to-workflow-activities-again.aspx) that might help you.

Comment: I think I probably explained my question rather badly. I know how to pass arguments to activities - the issue is that in an ideal world, I'd like to pass in a VB expression for an argument at runtime that itself refers to arguments/variables in the workflow, and have it be evaluated *at runtime* based on the values of those arguments/variables in the currently-executing context. I think I may be out of luck though.

Comment: I see - yes that doesn't work.  There are probably other ways to accomplish whatever it is that you want to do though.

Comment: The two options I came up with in the end were: (a) parse the expressions and evaluate them at runtime myself, or (b) construct a dictionary of possible expressions and look up the results of evaluating them at runtime. I eventually ended up choosing the latter in this particular scenario, because there was a more or less fixed set of expressions I needed to evaluate.